# Deserializing a null field that previously contained a value when it was serialized

Tags: c#, xml, field, deserialization, nullable

I have read many posts regarding deserialization of nullable fields but have not run across the following scenario:

1. Serialize an object with a nullable field that *contains* a value ("nil" attribute is not added to the node because it contains a value).
2. Remove the value from the nullable field in the xml (this happens via client-side processing).
3. Deserialize the xml.

Step 3 throws an error because the serializer does not treat the empty value of the nullable field as a null value (because "nil=true" is not specified).  It instead tries to convert the value to the field's data type (ex: Guid), which fails resulting in an error message that varies depending on the field's data type.

In the case of a Guid the error message is:

```
    System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document ([line number], [column number]). ---> System.FormatException: Unrecognized Guid format.
```

I should note that the serialization / deserialization methods we use are framework methods that use generics.

I'm looking for an elegant and generic solution.  The only feasible, generic solution I can think of is the following:

1. Convert the xml to an XDocument.
2. Use (less than desired) reflection to get all of the properties of the object that are reference types.
3. Add "nil=true" attribute to all nodes whose name is found in the list from #2 *and* has an empty value.
4. Use recursion to process each reference type in #2.

Note: Simply adding "nil=true" to all nodes that have an empty value will not work because the serializer will throw an error for value types that cannot be null.

[Edit] Code examples:

Sample data class

```
    public class DummyData
    {
        public Guid? NullableGuid { get; set; }
    }
```

Xml sent to client

```
    <DummyData>
    <NullableGuid>052ec82c-7322-4745-9ac1-20cc4e0f142d</NullableGuid>
    </DummyData>
```

Xml returned from client (error)

```
    <DummyData>
    <NullableGuid></NullableGuid>
    </DummyData>
```

Xml returned from client (desired result)

```
    <DummyData>
        <NullableGuid p2:nil="true" xmlns:p2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></NullableGuid>
    </DummyData>
```

Comment: Can you change the data object's `Guid` property to be a nullable `Guid?` type? EDIT: In the setter, if a `null` value is passed, you can assign whatever default `Guid` (I guess `Guid.Empty`) to the backing field.

Comment: The scenario I'm describing is in fact using a nullable Guid type.  The problem is that without nil="true", the serializer thinks the empty value is a valid Guid, not a null value.  Deserializing a null value works fine when "nil=true" is specified.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the responsibility of your client app to add the nil=true attribute to the xml if the value is blank? What are you using to serialize the data prior to it being sent to the server?

Comment: It will be very cumbersome to expect every script writer to handle this scenario.  Also, the client would not know whether or not the node is reference or value type. Adding "nil=true" to a value type will also result in an error because value types cannot be null (as noted at the end of the post).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with that pretty closely resembles my plan of attack described in the original question.

Disclaimer:  It is not short and most likely does not cover every deserialization scenario but seems to get the job done.

```
    public static T FromXml<T>(string xml)
    {
       string convertedXml = AddNilAttributesToNullableTypesWithNullValues(typeof(T), xml);
       var reader = new StringReader(convertedXml);
       var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (T));
       var data = (T) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
       reader.Close();
       return data;
    }

    private static string AddNilAttributesToNullableTypesWithNullValues(Type type, string xml)
    {
        string result;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(xml))
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            if (doc.Root != null)
                AddNilAttributesToNullableTypesWithNullValues(doc.Root, type);

            result = doc.ToString();
        }
        else
            result = xml;

        return result;
    }

    private static void AddNilAttributesToNullableTypesWithNullValues(XElement element, Type type)
      {
         if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("type");

         if (element == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("element");

         //If this type can be null and it does not have a value, add or update nil attribute
         //with a value of true.
         if (IsReferenceOrNullableType(type) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.Value))
         {
            XAttribute existingNilAttribute = element.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.LocalName == NIL_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);

            if (existingNilAttribute == null)
               element.Add(NilAttribute);
            else
               existingNilAttribute.SetValue(true);
         }
         else
         {
            //Process all of the objects' properties that have a corresponding child element.
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in type.GetProperties())
            {
               string elementName = GetElementNameByPropertyInfo(property);

               foreach (XElement childElement in element.Elements().Where(e =>
                  e.Name.LocalName.Equals(elementName)))
               {
                  AddNilAttributesToNullableTypesWithNullValues(childElement, property.PropertyType);
               }
            }

            //For generic IEnumerable types that have elements that correspond to the enumerated type,
            //process the each element.
            if (IsGenericEnumerable(type))
            {
               Type enumeratedType = GetEnumeratedType(type);

               if (enumeratedType != null)
               {
                  IEnumerable<XElement> enumeratedElements = element.Elements().Where(e =>
                     e.Name.LocalName.Equals(enumeratedType.Name));

                  foreach (XElement enumerableElement in enumeratedElements)
                     AddNilAttributesToNullableTypesWithNullValues(enumerableElement, enumeratedType);
               }
            }
         }
      }

      private static string GetElementNameByPropertyInfo(PropertyInfo property)
      {
         string overrideElementName = property.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<XmlElementAttribute>().Select(xmlElementAttribute => 
            xmlElementAttribute.ElementName).FirstOrDefault();
         return overrideElementName ?? property.Name;
      }

      private static Type GetEnumeratedType(Type type)
      {
         Type enumerableType = null;

         Type[] types = type.GetGenericArguments();

         if (types.Length == 1)
            enumerableType = types[0];

         return enumerableType;
      }

      public static bool IsGenericEnumerable(Type type)
      {
         return type.IsGenericType && type.GetInterfaces().Any(i => 
            i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>));
      }

      private static bool IsReferenceOrNullableType(Type type)
      {
         return !type.IsValueType || Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) != null;
      }

      private const string NIL_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "nil";
      private const string XML_SCHEMA_NAMESPACE = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

      private static XAttribute NilAttribute
      {
         get
         {
             if (_nilAttribute == null)
             {
                 XNamespace xmlSchemaNamespace = XNamespace.Get(XML_SCHEMA_NAMESPACE);
                 _nilAttribute = new XAttribute(xmlSchemaNamespace + NIL_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, true);
         }

        return _nilAttribute;
     }
  }
```